# Linux - Searching multiple filenames from a textfile and copy to location

Tags: linux

I have a text file containing the multiple names of files. I want to search these from a specific folder and copy it to another. Which Linux commands can I use to easily do this? Does grep, find commands help with this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You mean something like this?

```
while read -r file
do
    find /path/to/search -name "$file" -exec cp {} /new/folder/for/files \;
done < your_text_file_with_file_names
```

*To answer your comment:*

`while read -r file` <- here each line of your_text_file_with_file_names is assigned to the variable `file`.
`$file` outputs the value of the variable `file`. If you want to try it in the shell you're using:

```
> some_variable=whatever
> echo $some_variable
```

Comment: I have a question here. What do you mean by the word "file" and "$file" refer to in the above code?. Is it the 'textfile in which the file names'

Comment: I edited my answer to reply to your comment so it is more readable.